# Ruby Hash Alignment

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm trying to correct a linter error in my requests test file. I have a context block as follows:

```
context 'when the request is valid' do
  before(:each) do
    post '/api/v1/budgets',headers: authenticated_header(@user), params: {
      budget: valid_attributes
    }
  end
end
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
C: Layout/ArgumentAlignment: Align the arguments of a method call if they span more than one line.
```

What is the proper way to align this block?

Comment: Can't reproduce `Layout/ArgumentAligment` with Rubocop 0.77.0. Only  `Layout/SpaceAfterComma` at `budgets,headers:`. What's your Rubocop version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the RuboCop [`Layout/ArgumentAlignment`](https://docs.rubocop.org/en/stable/cops_layout/#layoutargumentalignment) documentation my guess would be:

```
context 'when the request is valid' do
  before(:each) do
    post '/api/v1/budgets',
         headers: authenticated_header(@user),
         params: { budget: valid_attributes }
  end
end
```

When you need multi-line `params` it should probably look like this:

```
context 'when the request is valid' do
  before(:each) do
    post '/api/v1/budgets',
         headers: authenticated_header(@user),
         params: {
           budget: valid_attributes
         }
  end
end
```

If you have more than one argument on the first line:

```
context 'when the request is valid' do
  before(:each) do
    post '/api/v1/budgets', headers: authenticated_header(@user), params: {
           budget: valid_attributes
         }
  end
end
```

When you have a long method name you could also consider moving the first argument to the next line to reduce intention for all other arguments:

```
context 'when the request is valid' do
  before(:each) do
    a_somewhat_long_method_name
      '/api/v1/budgets',
      headers: authenticated_header(@user),
      params: { budget: valid_attributes }
  end
end
```

The above amuses you use the default configuration (`:with_first_argument`).